# Delete duplicate values and replace with null (Power BI - SQL)

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, powerbi, transformation

first post :P. 
Anyway, so I am currently experiencing a problem after joining two tables in order to create a fact table. I did a left outer join on the `OrderDetail` table with the `SalesOrderHeader`. 
Now I have the problem that values like `SubTotal` or `TotalDue` were carried over from the `SalesHeader` to each of the lines in the `OrderDeatail` table....which doesn't make sense. So I was thinking to delete the duplicate values in the columns and replace them with null values, while keeping the rows intact. Power BI doesn't seem to have the capabilities for this (it uses the distinct statement). 
Does anyone have an idea how I can do this, or does anyone have a better more elegant solution to circumvent this?

Br,
Chris

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please include a mock-up of the table stuctures you are talking about, a mock-up of the data and of the expected result (no screen capture please) and also add the query you have tried in your question.

Comment: Hi there, so after thinking a little bit about the problem at hand I found it to be nonsensical to include the SalesOrderDetail into the OrderHeader table, which I wanted to use as the Fact_Sales. So now I simply keep it as a SalesDetail dimension in the Star Schema. Now everything is working for me . 

Thanks guys!